# evitar zoom al hacer doble click en movil jquery

Tags: click, zoom

El problema surge cuando el contenido de la pantalla no cabe completamente en moviles y hace un pequeño scrool horizontal, no me permite hacer doble click sobre la pantalla ya que al hacerlo me activa el zoom, acerca un poco la pantalla.

Habría alguna forma de evitar ese zoom al hacer doble click? He leido en esta pagina y en google y no he encontrado nada. Estoy usando Java script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día para evitar hacer zoom en moviles te recomiendo que en ti viewport no lo permitas de la siguiente manera espero eso resuelva tu duda

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,  me funciona bien en la mayoria de los navegadores pero con el Crhome no me funciona, imagino que será algún problema de compatibilidad.